# Viewing Error Details When Launching .desktop Files

Tags: .desktop, intellij

I created a .desktop launcher file for an application, but I cannot launch it. It says **There was an error launching the application**. I'm new to Linux and don't know how and where to see the error details. Just in case, the .desktop file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Icon=/opt/idea/bin/idea.png
Exec="/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

By the way, the launcher was created by the application (Intellij IDEA), not manually, but, anyway, I must be missing something.

Also, the desktop-file-validate utility yields no validation errors for the file.

So, the question is: how to see error logs, for more details about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

#### Validating .desktop files

There is a tool to validate `.desktop` files: ***[desktop-file-utils](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils/)***

- Download the latest tarball from [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/desktop-file-utils/releases/).

#### To install

- Unzip the file, `cd` into the unzipped folder's directory and run the commands:

  ```
  ./configure --prefix=/usr && make
  ```

  and

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```

  as described [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/desktop-file-utils.html)

#### To use it

*Quoted from the link:*, the `desktop-file-utils` can be run with the following commands:

---

```
desktop-file-edit
```

is used to modify an existing desktop file entry.

---

```
desktop-file-install
```

is used to install a new desktop file entry. It is also used to rebuild or modify the MIME-types application database.

---

```
desktop-file-validate
```

is used to verify the integrity of a desktop file.

---

```
update-desktop-database
```

is used to update the MIME-types application database.

---

The **third** option, ran with the `.desktop` file as an argument:

```
desktop-file-validate <.desktop_file>
```

will no doubt be the most interesting for you.

#### Note

When I tested the `desktop-file-utils`, it seemed to be more picky then necessary, and there were not many `.desktop` files that "survived" the test without at least a warning.

The good news is then that it is unlikely that the error, that makes your file fail, will be missed by the utility.

Comment: As I already mentioned, I tried desktop-file-validate but it didn't complain. Actually I was able to create a working .desktop file by just doing it right before the application loaded for the first time. Probably there's a stupid bug in the application itself instead of some serious issue or something... Thanks

Comment: Ah how could I have missed that? I was probably posting at the time of your edit...

Comment: Probably, but anyway, +1 for a comprehensive and well-constructed answer, which might be helpful for someone else in the future :) Cheers